# Should I wait until my muscles are 100% free of any signal of soreness before training for strength again?

Tags: strength-training, recovery, muscle-soreness, muscle-recovery, overtraining

I am trying to avoid injuries at all costs while still training for strength. I seem not to have the greatest recovery ability (42 yr male, healthy but [unable to sleep more than 6 hours a day on average](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/23636/less-sleep-the-night-before-in-order-to-sleep-more-the-night-after-a-strength-w)).

I work out once every four days (I was training once every three days but thanks to this useful site I [became aware a month ago that it was too much for me](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22321/can-a-two-weeks-pause-have-a-positive-impact-on-strength-training)). But even now, the night before the next strength training I can still press hard on my muscles and feel some light soreness.

It is not pain. And I need to press hard with a finger in order to feel that soreness. But it is there, perhaps signaling that my muscles have not yet recovered. **Does that mean I am overtraining?** I monitor other variables, like my RHR, that usually [rises a bit each day before a workout](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/23605/why-does-my-rhr-rise-every-day-after-a-strength-workout) but returns to normal one day later.

Comment: Nope. You don't need to wait until your muscles are 100% of soreness. BTW, is there any reason working out every 3 days is too much for you?

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD Because I returned from an incidental two-week pause and found myself fully energyzed, stronger and able to increase my reps in an unexpected amount. Then I decided to insert an additional rest day between workouts and it has worked like a charm. (By the way, nice name, I have laughed aloud suddently after remembering where it comes from, i.ie. that Superman II scene)

Comment: As long as it works for you, that's good. Do you have a specific goal in mind: strength training, hypertrophy, looking good?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it healthy to exercise a muscle when it's still sore?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/872/is-it-healthy-to-exercise-a-muscle-when-its-still-sore)

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD I train for strength alone. But not towards barbell weightlifting. I would like to be able to do pull ups eventually, though I am in no hurry. For the moment I am progressing very slowly by means of BW squats, inverted rows and push ups. And some "full can" lateral raises for the lateral deltoid and supraspinatus. I do some light cardio too in a stationary bike, while I wait for the summer to come, where I will swim again like I did a few months ago instead of the bike. I stopped running because I got knee aches and I didn't want any interference with the squats.

Comment: Google "Grease The Groove" on how to make bodyweight exercises a daily affair without much soreness :). I think it'll tremendously help you.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD Thanks! This is trickier than expected. For me, training while avoiding injury starts feeling a bit like [Neo avoiding bullets](http://www.redusers.com/noticias/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/bullet-time.jpg)

Comment: Lol.....with bodyweight exercises, you're unlikely to injure yourself unless you're doing the exercises the wrong way. And depending on the intensity, the soreness *(the-OMG-I-cannot-lift-my-arms-anymore-soreness)* shouldn't last more than a day.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD My technique is nearly perfect and I perform the exercises very slowly, specially the eccentric part of the movements (tempo ~ 4 s for the eccentric, ~ 1 s for the concentric phase with a 1 s pause in between). With such slow movements, you can get to volitional failure easily without the need of high weigth, which in turn is supposed to be safer for joints and tendons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muscle soreness is not an indicator of overtraining. Go ahead and work out.

Comment: Thanks! I may seem a bit paranoid, but perhaps you might remember how I hurted myself a couple of years ago... Multiple tendinitis and eventually a whole SLAP tear in a shoulder... I learnt my lesson...

Comment: @Mephisto Remember that your recovery ability is not a static target. You should try working out more frequently and see how you feel. The key is to notice and keep track of the signs of overtraining.

Comment: I try to achieve a system as independent as possible from my subjectivity. One of my conclusions from my past injuries is that perhaps I lack proprioception or something, because it is very easy for me to push too hard and realize it only when it is too late. You should see how I am programming now each workout with a spreadseet, 3RM and total work estimates in order to progress in a slow, safe pace... How I monitor my heart rate, sleep times, bodyweigth... I should write a book.

Comment: Apart from anomalous rest hear rate, disrupted sleep and progress plateaus, are there any other signs I should try to detect?

Comment: @Mephisto There are plenty. Joint soreness, lethargy, inability to get warmed up during training, trouble waking up. But that's it's own question.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I was getting a weak but persistent soreness in my elbow ("joint soreness") that has gone away after changing from working out once every 3 days to 1 in 4 days. So that is another sign of overtraining. Very interesting.

Comment: I suggest you might add that list of overtraining symptoms (together with the ones I listed) to your answer if you like it so.